# Seamless Cubemap Generation to Map on Quadcube

Tags: opengl, random, texture-mapping, distortion, procedural-generation

I have a quadcube generated from a cube that I want to texture.
Six textures are generated randomly.
If I mapped them directly onto the quadcube, they would look very distorted, so I distort them beforehand using [pincushion distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)#Radial_distortion) so the distortions cancel each other out. The problem is that by pre-distorting the texture, parts of it are being cut off so very ugly seams occur.

How could I modify the texture generation to achieve seamless transitions between the six textures? Or do I do it all wrong?

Because I cannot post more than two links in one question, here is a [gallery containing some images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VUfc.jpg) of my problem.

I'm thankful for every kind of help. Thanks.

Comment: add rendering code and sample textures ... I would use rectangular texture mapped to spherical coordinates of vertexes... see [Bump-map a sphere with a texture map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32558700/2521214) and [Applying map of the earth texture a Sphere](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31804515/2521214). Do not forget that the texture must be seamless too [make seamless height-map texture for sphere planet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33098572/2521214) and lastly [triangles are nicer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29139125/2521214)