# Algorithm to make images seamless

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Does anyone know of an algorithm that can make images seamless. In the same way this works:

https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/make-seamless-texture.php (see 3rd method)

It does some sort of smooth copy and then image brightness adjustment

Comment: Not my domain, but I think textural inpainting might be related to what you want.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I'll look this up!

Comment: There are many possible ways to make images seamless. Please state your specific requirements. Especially comment on: What is the difference between the images, are you willing to sacrifice part of the images, how are they combined, how many different images are there, are they overlapping? This will help make this question answerable.

Comment: one possibility is this: [make seamless height-map texture for sphere (planet)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098572/2521214) it is similar to the option 3  smoothed copies of all sides  but it is just half of it (only mirrors)